# Input data in database from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postgresql, input

I am storing a value in a variable in javascript. Than I have created a hidden  tag in order to access the variable from the codebehind and store it in the database. BUT  for some reason on the line  `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` it is givig me the following error on attempting to input data in database:

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error at end of input
```

The following is the input tag in asp:

```
    <div>
        <input id="hidden_value" type="hidden" runat="server"/>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />

    </div>
```

The following is how I am calling the hidden input in javascript and set it to a value:

```
var store_altitude;
store_altitude = some_value;
document.getElementById("hidden_value").value=store_altitude;
```

And the following is the codebehind:

```
 using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    Response.Write(hidden_value.Value);
                    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into altitude select nextval('altitude_id_seq'),"+hidden_value.Value, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "$(document).ready(function(){alert('problem with connection')});", true);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using parameters?

Comment: Good point @ta.speot.is BUT  do you think it would make a difference for the error i am getting?

Comment: Well yes, if `hidden_value` is meant to be interpreted as a string or something.

Comment: So how should I amend the code please? @ta.speot.is

Comment: What is returned if you execute the following code: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "$(document).ready(function(){alert('hidden_value=" + hidden_value.Value + "')});", true);

Comment: This behaviour must be due to special characters or "'" in the hiddenfield value. Try using parameter. Also you can try to print the sqlcommand that is made dynamically then pasting in sql to see what is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should ***NEVER, EVER* build sql by string concatenation** with parameters.  It's slow, error prone, and you've opened yourself up to SQL injection.  In your case, it looks like **any web hacker could trivially gain full access to your database**.

Since you're writing raw sql and not using an ORM, you unfortunately are confronted by the fact that ADO.NET's API is pretty terrible.  I'd strongly suggest using something like [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), which would allow expressing your query roughly as follows:

```
conn.Execute(@"
    insert into altitude
    values (extval('altitude_id_seq'), @hiddenVal)",
       new { hiddenVal = hidden_value.Value});
```

There are other lightweight ADO.NET wrappers; many are just fine, [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) simply happens to be well known.

As a minor issue, though not strictly required, I find it to be more readable to include the column names you're inserting rather than implicitly using them in whatever order the DB has them listed.  But if you're absolutely sure the schema won't change, there's no issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove runat="server" from hidden_value and in code side user request["hidden_value"]; to get value of hidden_value.

Comment: I am getting the following error in the codebehind ; rquest does not exists in the current context. @Bhargav Mistri

Comment: use this Request["hidden_value"].Trim();